# Календарь на UICollectionView

Tags: xcode, objective-c, календарь

Пишу свой календарь по типу как на `iOS7` используя `CollectionView`. Я беру, например, количество дней в текущем месяце, делаю итерацию и получаю каждый день как отдельный объект и заполняю ячейки. Вверху у меня статический View с днями недели. как мне сдвигать заполнение ячеек на `CollectionView` согласно первому дню месяца и дне недели?

[ScreenShot](http://s22.postimg.org/kqa7pj0w1/Screen_Shot_2013_08_13_at_0_11_02.png)

Comment: Как насчет забивать "лишние" ячейки пустышками?

Comment: да, мне че-то кажеться нужно получить первый день недели и сделать математику. я тока еще до конца не понял логику

Comment: Двухмерный массив?

Comment: тоже думаю в эту сторону. тогда нужно бы захватить и год в массив и сделать его трехмерным. Вопрос в том, может у кого алгоритм завалялся?

Comment: UICollectionViewLayout - это то, что вам нужно. Класс, который отвечает за расположение ячеек колекции
[дыц][1], [дыц][2]


  [2]: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UICollectionViewLayout


  [1]: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH5-SW1

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вставлял пустые `UIView`, это проще, чем писать свой `UICollectionViewLayout`.